# global name 'layoutGrid' is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

I want to disable a widget when the video is running, so I created a class ScreenVideo, in which I defined a layoutGrid and placed in it button with filenames.

When I call on_press callback, the error I get:

> global name 'layoutGrid' is not defined.

```
class ScreenVideo(Screen):
    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenVideo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
        root =  FloatLayout(size=(Window.width, Window.height))  
        layoutGrid = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=70, size_hint_y=None)  
        layoutGrid .bind(minimum_height=layoutGrig.setter('height')) #for scroll 
        ....
     
        for filename in os.listdir(folder location):
            filename2 = filename.replace(".mp4", "")
            btn = Button(text=str(filename2), font_size='25sp', italic = True)
            btn.bind(on_release=self.callback)  #on_press
            layoutGrid.add_widget(btn)

    def callback(self, instance):
        ...
        layoutGrid.disabled = True
```

Comment: self.layoutGrid.disabled = True
 AttributeError: 'ScreenVideo' object has no attribute 'layoutGrid'

Answer (score 0):

Make `layoutGrid` an attribute of your instance:

```
class ScreenVideo(Screen):
    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenVideo, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        root =  FloatLayout(size=(Window.width, Window.height))  
        self.layoutGrid = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=70, size_hint_y=None)  
        self.layoutGrid.bind(minimum_height=self.layoutGrid.setter('height')) #for scroll 
        ....

        for filename in os.listdir(folder location):
            filename2 = filename.replace(".mp4", "")
            btn = Button(text=str(filename2), font_size='25sp', italic = True)
            btn.bind(on_release=self.callback)  #on_press
            self.layoutGrid.add_widget(btn)

    def callback(self, instance):
        ...
        self.layoutGrid.disabled = True
```

Comment: I made layoutGrid an attribute, but I keep getting the error:   self.layoutGrid.bind(minimum_height=layoutGrid.setter('height')) #for scroll
NameError: global name 'layoutGrid' is not defined

Comment: I had missed the one in the parameters. Updated

Comment: Nice! If you feel that this answer solved your question, you may [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)